# Print Program works, but prints extra letters/numbers

Tags: python, printing, command-line, sys

I am trying to get a simple program to take command line arguments and print them out. Any name plus a character string of explanation marks. **example:  Bob !!!!**

```
import sys

def hello(name):
    name = name + "!!!!"
    print(hello,name)

def main():
    hello(sys.argv[1])

main()
```

It correctly prints out Bob!!!!, but with also some other stuff:

**function hello at 0x7f69465145f0 Bob!!!!** with < > around the whole thing except Bob!!!!

I am not sure why it will not simply print out, Bob!!!!, normally without the other stuff.

Also, the mix of number/letters within the < > changes every time I run it. The **function hello at** and **Bob!!!!** stays the same.

Comment: Python funtions are objects too, you can print them, and this mix of numbers/letters is its id, you can check it with `print hex(id(hello))`. For cPython this id reflects memory address where function descriptor is stored, so it is different for each run.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that was the ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `hello` is the name of function you've defined, thus `print(hello, name)` prints both the function object, and the string variable. If you want to print `hello Bob !!!!!`, use `print('hello', name)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def hello(name):
    print('Hello, '+name+'!!!')
```